# Getting a single-column slide when using Quarto to render a Jupyter notebook to Powerpoint

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pandoc, quarto

I am trying to use Quarto to render a Jupyter notebook to Powerpoint slides. I would like to render one slide as a "Content with Caption" slide, which is the style intended for single-column slides with both text and non-text, as per the [Quarto docs on Powerpoint](https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/powerpoint.html).

How can I generate both text and a graph in the same column in Jupyter?

Using the default Pandoc Powerpoint template, I have tried:

```
(markdown chunk) text
(code chunk) graph
```

which renders as a two-column slide

```
(code chunk) print('my text as a string')
graph
```

which also renders as a two-column slide (with code formatting for the text now)

```
(markdown chunk)
:::: {.columns}

::: {.column width="100%"}
text
(code chunk)
graph
(markdown chunk)
:::

::::
```

which prints the text as intended in a single column but omits the graph entirely.

Is it possible to do this? Thank you.